# CIContext drawImage:inRect:fromRect: scaling

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-image

I am using `CIContext` method `- (void)drawImage:(CIImage *)im inRect:(CGRect)dest fromRect:(CGRect)src` to draw my image to screen. But I need to implement zoom-in/zoom-out method. How could I achieve it? I think zoom-in could be achieved increasing `dest` rect, because apple docs says:

```
The image is scaled to fill the destination rectangle.
```

But what about zoom-out? Because if `dest` rectangle is scaled down, then image is drawn in it's actual size, but only part of image is visible then (part that fits in `dest` rectangle).

What could you suggest?

Comment: Did you actually try it and observe that behavior, or are you just guessing what might happen?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [this](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) for image resizing (zooming). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CIFilter to resize your CIImage before drawing. Quartz Composer comes with a good example of using this filter. Just look up the description of the Image Resize filter in QC.

**EDIT:**
Another good filter for scaling is CILanczosScaleTransform. There is a [snippet](http://josealobato.tumblr.com/post/6615949941/cocoa-snippet-image-resize-with-ci) demonstrating basic usage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this little [toy app I made](https://github.com/foundry/drawingtest)

It's to demonstrate the NSImage version of your CIContext method:

```
- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)dstRect 
          fromRect:(NSRect)srcRect 
         operation:(NSCompositingOperation)op 
          fraction:(CGFloat)delta
```

I did this to find out exactly how the rects relate to each other. It's interactive, you can play with the sliders and move/zoom the images. Not a solution, but it might help you work things out.